# Why is layout stretch factor limited to a certain size in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qlayout

I'm currently working with PyQt5, where I'm designing a GUI using the [Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html) app.

However, I'm encountering a strange behavior where, within a layout (could be horizontal / vertical), the stretch factor between two elements is not infinitely tunable, and actually depends on the size of the layout window.

Here's an example:

[image]

So this is a standard vertical layout with two empty list widgets inside where I applied a stretch factor of `1,3`. Now basically I cannot apply any bigger stretch factor. Changing the `1,3` to `1,5` for instance, doesn't affect the layout.

[image]

However, if the overall size of the layout is increased, the factor `1,5` can be applied

[image]

**So my question is**: Is there a way to force any stretch factor no matter the size of the layout window?

(I already verified my min and max sizes, and they're set to :
[image] )

Comment: Could you post the contents of the .ui file you are using in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by the [minimumSizeHint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop). The minimum size must be explicitly set to a non-zero value in order for the layout to resize smaller than the minimum size hint. Alternatively, the [size-policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) could be to `Ignored`. So *either* of the settings shown below should work for your example:

[image]

With a layout stretch of `1,5`, this will now allow resizing like this:

[image]